# Value Tuple initialization is counter-intuitive

Tags: c#, .net, tuples

In the Sunday evening I have been watching some conferences this time I get hands on this one [Conference Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aUbXGs7YTGo)

Where I found out pretty interesting think there is simple code example:

```
struct Point
{
    private double x;

    public double X { get => x; set => x = value; }

    private double y;

    public double Y { get => y; set => y = value; }

    public Point(double x, double y) => (this.x, this.y) = (x, y);

    public void SwapCode() => (X, Y) = (Y, X);

}
```

**In Main**:

```
var point = new Point(10.0, 11.0);

Console.WriteLine($"x: {point.X}, y: {point.Y}");
point.SwapCode();
Console.WriteLine($"x: {point.X}, y: {point.Y}");
```

And there is output of this :

```
x: 10, y: 11
x: 11, y: 10
```

So there is some questions:

How does it works ?

1. What I mean by that is Tuples should be translate into `Tuple<T, K>` which should be initialize with copy of the values but there it assign values to the variables at least for me it's kind of counter intuitive.
2. And i wonder if it's just sugar syntax think or there is happen some magic under this what make perfect sense but I can't spot it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly *structs* should be *immutable*. Even though you can do this, you probably shouldn't.

Secondly, your `SwapCode` is actually doing this, [as seen here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCiDetE9wZwBcAnAVwGMDEAFAewEsA7A7XHLGVzgByLoDcAhgQCmiACY0SAIwA2ogB4BuWC044E4ybNEANTIgDmwygF4AfIiWI8xxOct3EgmSWGLEAXxUc1OHvyFRCWk5RABPZRhVNQ1g7UQATX0jUwsI61t7MMdnV3cvKJ9fDVpGAgAKOND5ABpNENEwgEo7C3KCAAs6PAA6WsRO7p7mx3L+5sjozg0QABZEAGUAdwEuVBoxYXKW+3KdOoSdxHKEup0myaLcAtYZ+YBZbcxogo8gA).

```
public void SwapCode()
{
   double num = Y;
   double num2 = X;
   double num4 = X = num;
   num4 = (Y = num2);
}
```

Yeah, it's a little strange. However, it's just a little syntactic magic introduced in C#7. What it is actually doing is using a `deconstruct` method (the terminology *.Net* uses) to provide a set of *out arguments* for each of the params you want to extract. In this case, it's the properties/field you supplied!

To see it a little clearer, consider these two functionally equivalent code blocks

```
(int x, int y) asd = (1, 2); // create a Value Tuple
(int x, int y) = asd; // deconstruct it
(x, y) = (x, y); // assign to the deconstructed type

// All the above now has the swapped values
// they are all pointing to the same variables/memory

// You could even take this further by

x = 10;
y = 11;

// Once again, x and y, asd, and (x, y) all have the same values
// Because they are the same

// ----------------------------------------------------

int x = 1;
int y = 2;
(x, y) = (y, x); // we are just deconstructing our original variables

// All the above now has the swapped values
// they are all pointing to the same variables/memory
```

<sub>***Note*** : As you can see, this is also a slightly more succinct way of swapping 2 variables as you don't have to use a temp variables, your friendly CLR does it for you</sub>

Anyway, you shouldn't be doing this with a `struct` anyway, they really should be immutable for various reasons